# How to get <p:selectOneMenu> value using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

How I can get select component value using Jquery or javascript

MyJSF code below

```
<h:form>
      <p:selectOneMenu style="width:150px" id="id" onchange="onCall()">
              <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
              <f:selectItem itemLabel="Other" itemValue="Other"></f:selectItem>
       </p:selectOneMenu>
       <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="flag"/>
       <p:inputText id="name" value="#{mybean.value}/>
 </h:form>
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: I have tried some code but no one work

Comment: it would be better if you could post your rendered html, instead of jsf code this way, also if you could post your javascript as you mentioned you have applied some inline js event.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Primefaces provides a Javascript API for its components, you can access it through the `widgetVar`

***xhtml***

```
<p:selectOneMenu widgetVar="selectWV">               
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

***JS***

```
PF('selectWV').getSelectedValue();//gets the value
PF('selectWV').getSelectedLabel();//gets the label
```

Comment: Is there any option to set <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="flag"/> to true and hide  <p:inputText id="name" value="#{mybean.value}/> on change?

Comment: Of course, but this question is not related the question asked above, you may ask another question explaining your case, in this case we avoid confusion ...

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the `this` in this function:

```
onchange="onCall(this)"
```

and i am assuming you have defined this `onCall` function in the global scope, then you can do this:

```
onCall(el){
    alert(el.value);
}
```

Comment: why would you debug with `alert` and not `console.log()`?

Comment: this is just an example where OP has to look for answers. I know `console.log()` is better to use but this is just i would say my assumption to tell OP try doing this way to get the values in your function.

Comment: Oh working, but i want set checkbox=true value as well