# Storing the value of selected item from a p:selectOneListbox into a variable on a button click

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to save the value of selected item from p:selectOneListbox on a button click using jquery.

Tried to replicate but it didn't work for me  : [How to get the value of <p:selectOneMenu> in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093432/how-to-get-the-value-of-pselectonemenu-in-jquery/8093618)

```
<p:selectManyMenu id="advanced1" widgetVar='commmentWidget'
                        value="#{decisionTreeBean.option1}"  showCheckbox="true" styleClass="XXXX">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{decisionTreeBean.XXXX}" var="X"
                            itemLabel="#{X}" itemValue="#{X}" />
                    </p:selectManyMenu>
```

Below jquery didn't work (name attribute is the name from the generated HTML)

```
jQuery(".generateBtn").on("click",function(event){
                     var $element = jQuery("select[name='A3128:searchForm:basic1_input']option:selected").val();
                    alert($element);

                });
```

[image: Generated HTML:]

How do I store the text value of the item selected from selectOneListbox into  a variable.

Comment: Please refrain from adding tags in the title. They are sort of automatically added by stackoverflow. And effectively this is not PrimeFaces related but a pure html/javascript/jquery question. And why are you trying to do all this pure client-side?

Comment: Maybe a blank is missing in front of `option:selected`